# Refund of Cable-car Ticket in case of Cancellation on account of Bad Weather

Tags: cancellations, bavaria, gondolas-and-cable-cars

If I book winter tickets for Zugpitze (non-skier) online and on the day of trip the cable car and/or train is not operating due to bad weather conditions, then would there be any refund of the ticket?

I feel there should be otherwise it makes little sense to book it in advance, especially in winters.

Note: On the booking page I tried to see *general terms and conditions* but on clicking on it i get to the page with message "probably snowed in, we are looking for it!" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation of the German [Allgemeine Beförderungsbedingungen](https://zugspitze.de/de/service/ueberuns/abb) (using [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator), emphasis mine):

> **Cable cars**
>
> § 8 Exemption from the obligation to carry
>
> Events of force majeure such as weather conditions, strikes, lock-outs, operational disruptions or unforeseeable circumstances which may impair the safety of the transport operation shall postpone the obligation to transport for the duration of the hindrance and a reasonable start-up period or shall be omitted due to the fact that repairs cannot be remedied or are not carried out on time. **In these cases there is no right to a refund.** Likewise, no reimbursement shall be made in the event of weather-related impairments or for unused tickets as a result of illness, injury or early departure.
>
> **Rail transport / rack-and-pinion railway**
>
> § 6 Ticket prices and tickets
>
> (6) **In the event of non-use of a ticket, the fare shall be refunded on application against return of the unvalidated ticket.** If the ticket has only been used for part of the journey, the difference between the fare paid and the normal fare for the distance travelled shall be refunded. Applications must be submitted immediately, at the latest within six months, to the railway administration.
>
> § 8 Exemption from the obligation to carry
>
> Events of force majeure, e.g. weather conditions, strikes, lock-outs, operational disruptions or unforeseeable circumstances which may impair the safety of the operation of the vehicle shall postpone the obligation to transport for the duration of the hindrance and an appropriate start-up period or shall be omitted due to repairs which cannot be repaired or which are not carried out on time.

But: Recently, passengers who were stuck on the cable car and train for an hour due to a power outage got a refund ([German newspaper aricle](https://www.merkur.de/lokales/garmisch-partenkirchen/zugspitzbahn-stromausfall-menschen-steckten-in-gondeln-fest-9846578.html)).

---

German original:

> **Seilbahnen**
>
> § 8 Entbindung von der Beförderungspflicht
>
> Ereignisse höherer Gewalt z. B. Witterungsverhältnisse, Streik, Aussperrung, Betriebsstörungen oder unvorhersehbare Umstände, die die Sicherheit des Fahrbetriebes beeinträchtigen können, lassen die Beförderungspflicht um die Dauer der Behinderung und einer angemessenen Anlaufzeit verschieben oder wegen nicht behebbarer oder nicht zeitgerechter Behebung entfallen. Ein Anspruch auf Rückvergütung besteht in diesen Fällen nicht. Ebenso erfolgt keine Rückvergütung bei witterungsbedingten Einbußen oder für nicht genutzte Fahrkarten infolge von Krankheit, Verletzung oder vorzeitiger Abreise.
>
> **Schienenverkehr/Zahnradbahn**
>
> § 6 Fahrpreise und Fahrausweise
>
> (6)    Bei Nichtbenutzung eines Fahrausweises wird auf Antrag gegen Rückgabe des nicht entwerteten Fahrausweises der Fahrpreis zurückerstattet. Ist der Fahrausweis nur auf einer Teilstrecke benutzt worden, so wird der Unterschied zwischen dem gezahlten Fahrpreis und dem gewöhnlichen Fahrpreis für die zurückgelegte Strecke erstattet. Anträge sind unverzüglich, spätestens innerhalb von sechs Monaten bei der Verwaltung der Bahn zu stellen.
>
> § 8 Entbindung von der Beförderungspflicht
>
> Ereignisse höherer Gewalt, z. B. Witterungsverhältnisse, sowie Streik, Aussperrung, Betriebsstörungen oder unvorhersehbare Umstände, die die Sicherheit des Fahrbetriebes beeinträchtigen können, lassen die Beförderungspflicht um die Dauer der Behinderung und einer angemessenen Anlaufzeit verschieben oder wegen nicht behebbaren oder nicht zeitgerechten Behebungen entfallen.